# Azure CLI error json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type unstructured.detector

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-cli

I am new to Azure Kubernetes Service. I have created an Azure Kubernetes cluster and tried to deploy some workload in it. The .yaml file as follows

```
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Namespace
  metadata:
    name: azure-vote
  spec:
    finalizers:
      - kubernetes
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: azure-vote-back
    namespace: azure-vote
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: azure-vote-back
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: azure-vote-back
      spec:
        nodeSelector:
          beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
        containers:
          - name: azure-vote-back
            image: mcr.microsoft.com/oss/bitnami/redis:6.0.8
            env:
              - name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
                value: 'yes'
            resources:
              requests:
                cpu: 100m
                memory: 128Mi
              limits:
                cpu: 250m
                memory: 256Mi
            ports:
              - containerPort: 6379
                name: redis
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: azure-vote-back
    namespace: azure-vote
  spec:
    ports:
      - port: 6379
    selector:
      app: azure-vote-back
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: azure-vote-front
    namespace: azure-vote
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: azure-vote-front
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: azure-vote-front
      spec:
        nodeSelector:
          beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
        containers:
          - name: azure-vote-front
            image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1
            resources:
              requests:
                cpu: 100m
                memory: 128Mi
              limits:
                cpu: 250m
                memory: 256Mi
            ports:
              - containerPort: 80
            env:
              - name: REDIS
                value: azure-vote-back
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: azure-vote-front
    namespace: azure-vote
  spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
      - port: 80
    selector:
      app: azure-vote-front
```

When I deploy this .yaml via Azure CLI it gives me a validation error but doesn't indicate where is it? When I run the kubectl apply -f ./filename.yaml --validate=false it gives **"cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type unstructured.detector"** error. However, when I run the same yaml in Azure portal UI it runs without any error. Appreciate if someone can mention the reason for this and how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to run the code you have provided in the ***Portal*** as well as ***Azure CLI***. It successfully got created in *Portal UI* by adding the `YAML code` but using *Azure CLI* I received the same error as you :

[image]

After doing some modifications in your `YAML file` and validating it , I ran the same command again and it successfully got deployed in ***Azure CLI***:

**YAML File:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: azure-vote
spec:
  finalizers:
    - kubernetes
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-back
  namespace: azure-vote
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: azure-vote-back
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azure-vote-back
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: azure-vote-back
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/oss/bitnami/redis:6.0.8
        env:
        - name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "yes"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-back
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
  selector:
    app: azure-vote-back
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-front
  namespace: azure-vote
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: azure-vote-front
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azure-vote-front
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": linux
      containers:
      - name: azure-vote-front
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: REDIS
          value: "azure-vote-back"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-front
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: azure-vote-front
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]